# how to map original value instead of True and False in python

Tags: python, pandas

i am trying to get all the value which contain (/) in another column which doesn't contain (/) should be marked zero

i tried this

```
    splits2 = df.COLUMN_2.str.contains('/')
```

but it just find true and false value.
can i map true value with original value present in column_2

for (/) it marks true and which does not contain (/) it marks false but i want to place original value in place true
for now it just marking true and false

Comment: Does `splits2 = df.COLUMN_2[df.COLUMN_2.str.contains('/')` solve the problem? Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question. If not, can you provide the expected output for that example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
splits2 = df.COLUMN_2.where(df.COLUMN_2.str.contains('/'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
splits2 = np.where(df.COLUMN_2.str.contains('/'), df.COLUMN_2,0)
```